# Incluir AND o similar dentro de un FOR en batch

Tags: batch, .bat, msdos

Perdon la ignorancia con batchs pero estoy aprendiendo. Con mi .bat estoy filtrando los archivos *.txt de varias carpetas para enviarlos por Sftp. Tomo las rutas de las carpetas de origen de rutas.txt. El tema es que en esas carpetas hay muchos txt, y solo necesito enviar los que se llaman file001.txt y file005.txt , como seria la sintaxis como para aprovechar el bucle y mandar solo esos 2 archivos ? Copio el código que funciona correctamente pero envía todos los *.txt :

```
for /f "delims=; tokens=1,2,3,4" %%A in (
rutas.txt
) do send-winscp.cmd %%B*.txt %%D*.txt
```